# PSpice OrCAD Adding Diode and Unknown Source

Tags: voltage, diodes, source

On the PSPice OrCAD, how do you add a diode with a 0.7V forward bias and a unknown voltage source?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you're trying to do - are you looking for a DC sweep?

Comment: @Kynit I'm trying to solve for the unknown voltage. I am using a bias point sweep.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know if PSpice can hold an element voltage constant and calculate a source voltage based on it.

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to do? Can you just plop an op-amp in there to force the voltage to 700mV?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my interpretation of your question. I might be tackling this the wrong way.

I think you've got some circuits around a diode and you want to find what the input voltage has to be for the diode voltage to be 700mV. I just tried a simple series resistor and diode.

I drew the circuit in Orcad Capture and didn't specify the voltage on the source:

[image: Orcad Capture schematic screenshot]

Then I set up a simulation profile to sweep the voltage source over a range of voltages:

[image: Simulation profile screenshot]

Finally, I plotted the voltage across the diode and used the cursor to find where the diode voltage was 700mV. I found that V1 = 1.88V at this point.

[image: Output screenshot]

Maybe you can take this idea and apply it to whatever circuits you're analyzing.

Comment: http://imgur.com/BYMiVjP Thank you. This the circuit I'm trying to replicate on PSpice OrCAD.

Comment: Yes, it definitely looks like this technique would work for that circuit. You would have two voltage sources and you would sweep one.

Comment: How would you make the other voltage source contain an unknown parameter?

Comment: Here, my simulation profile only swept V1. If I added another voltage source V2 and set it to 5V, it wouldn't change in the DC sweep.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain how to not specify the voltage for a source?

Comment: It should be unspecified by default. I'm not sure that you even need to worry about it when you're doing a DC sweep. Take a look at the documentation for Orcad and see if you can get a good grasp on how to work DC sweeps.

Comment: It is 0Vdc as the default for me. I'm using the SOURCE library.